# Add PayPal Credit option to the PayPal button

Tags: paypal

The PayPal Credit (formerly BML) overview page says the following:

> How do I select PayPal Credit as my payment source?
>   There are two ways to choose PayPal Credit. Some merchants have a PayPal Credit option at checkout. If they do, you can simply choose that option. **If you don’t see a PayPal Credit option, check out with PayPal, and then you’ll have the option to select PayPal Credit as your payment method. Either way a window will appear on your screen where you’ll provide your date of birth and the last 4 digits of your Social Security number, and then agree to the terms and conditions**. Approval takes just seconds and you can complete your purchase.

I've tried several sites, and in some of them PayPal Credit appears as an option when you check out with PayPal (see Nordstrom, for example). In others, the PayPal Credit option does not appear (see KitchenAid). What parameter needs to be passed in the PayPal API for the Credit option to show up? I checked the PayPal button creator page, and there's no option to add PayPal Credit.

Answer (score 1):

**I realize this question is old, but the PayPal documentation is awful so this should save people time.**

If you're using the [PHP SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK) you can set the PayPal credit to be the default payment with this method.

```
$payer = new PayPal\Api\Payer();
$payer->setExternalSelectedFundingInstrumentType('CREDIT');
```

The JSON for it is this

```
"payer":{
    "payment_method":"paypal",
    "external_selected_funding_instrument_type":"CREDIT"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your account is eligible and enabled for PayPal Credit, you can use this parameter:
`USERSELECTEDFUNDINGSOURCE = BML`

in your [ExpressCheckout](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/) API call.